# Some Quick Launch items are not displayed on the task bar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

I just had a look at my task bar shortcuts folder (`%appdata%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar`) and found that many items appear multiple times there (e.g. "Firefox", "Firefox (1)", "Firefox (2)" etc.), but only one of these duplicate items is actually showing on the task bar. There are also some items in the folder which aren't present on the task bar at all.

How does Windows know which of the items in this folder to actually display on the task bar, and which ones to hide? Where is this information stored?

(Why do these duplicate items matter to me at all? Because I sometimes use the Cairo Desktop shell instead of explorer.exe when the latter decides to keep crashing for some reason, and Cairo Desktop *does* show all of the duplicate items on its task bar, which looks ridiculous, and takes up a lot of task bar space, of course.)

Comment: Windows keeps this hidden now so that software can't pin itself to your task bar. if your PC is part of an organization, there is a whole system for managing the icons: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/configure-windows-10-taskbar . Any duplicates not in use in that folder can probably just be cleaned out

Comment: Well, how do I know which ones are actually in use? How can I tell the duplicates apart? Also, the system for managing the icon seems rather complicated, and I couldn't find a location where such an XML file as described on the page you linked to is located ...

Comment: if you hover over the task bar icon, it will display the name like `Firefox (2)` using the name from the file in that folder like `Firefox (2).lnk`. The XML file process is only for use with group policy - I just included it in case you were using a corporate pc (and as an example that there's not a simple list somewhere to reference)

Comment: Ok, thanks! It worked like that for all the shortcuts except for those to explorer.exe, where I have three identically-named ones without any numbers in the names ...